Why is Python much faster than Dart for file read/write operations?
I am testing file read/write performance in both Python and Dart, and I encountered a surprising result: Python is significantly faster than Dart for these operations. Here are the times I recorded:
Python:

Write time: 10.28 seconds
Read time: 4.88 seconds
Total time: 15.16 seconds

Dart:

Write time: 79 seconds
Read time: 10 seconds
Total time: 90 seconds

I expected Dart to perform similarly or even better than Python in this context, so I'm puzzled by these results. I’m running both tests on the same system (Mac) with similar code structures to ensure a fair comparison.
Questions:

Are there any known reasons for this significant performance difference in file handling between Python and Dart?
Could specific libraries, encoding formats, or other system-level factors in Python or Dart affect file I/O speed?
Are there optimization techniques in Dart to improve file read/write performance?

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this discrepancy and how to potentially optimize Dart's file I/O performance.
Here's the Python code:
def benchmark(cnt=200):
    block_size = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" * (1024 * 1024)
    file_path = "large_benchmark_test.txt"

    start_time = time.time()
    with open(file_path, "w") as file:
        for _ in range(cnt):
            file.write(block_size)
    write_end_time = time.time()

    with open(file_path, "r") as file:
        while file.read(1024):
            pass
    read_end_time = time.time()

    write_time = write_end_time - start_time
    read_time = read_end_time - write_end_time
    total_time = read_end_time - start_time

    print(f"Python - Write: {write_time:.2f} s")
    print(f"Python - Read: {read_time:.2f} s")
    print(f"Python - Total: {total_time:.2f} s")
    os.remove(file_path)

And the Dart code:
void benchmark({int cnt=200}) {
  final blockSize = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' * 1024 * 1024;
  final filePath = 'large_benchmark_test.txt';
  final file = File(filePath);

  final writeStartTime = DateTime.now();
  final sink = file.openSync(mode: FileMode.write);
  for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    sink.writeStringSync(blockSize);
  }
  sink.closeSync();
  final writeEndTime = DateTime.now();
  final writeTime = writeEndTime.difference(writeStartTime).inSeconds;
  print("Dart (Synch) - Write: $writeTime s");
  
  final readStartTime = DateTime.now();
  final reader = file.openSync(mode: FileMode.read);
  while (true) {
    final buffer = reader.readSync(1024);
    if (buffer.isEmpty) break;
  }
  reader.closeSync();
  final readEndTime = DateTime.now();

  final readTime = readEndTime.difference(readStartTime).inSeconds;
  final totalTime = readEndTime.difference(writeStartTime).inSeconds;

  print("Dart (Synch) - Read: $readTime s");
  print("Dart (Synch) - Total: $totalTime s");
  file.deleteSync();
}


User have cross-posted the question on Reddit with some discussion going on: https://www.reddit.com/r/FlutterDev/comments/1glohox/why_is_python_so_much_faster_than_dart_for_file/

Would it be possible to re-run the benchmarks using benchmark(cnt: 10)? Are you observing a similar discrepancy?

@DanR yes it finished in 0s

I see, could you run benchmark(cnt: 10) using the function I posted below? This would measure writing/reading 260MB of data. And perhaps mention the Python score for cnt 10 as well.

The scores below were generated on an Intel i5-10210u with 16GB,
Python 3.10.0, Dart SDK version: 3.5.3 (stable) (Wed Sep 11 16:22:47 2024 +0000) on "windows_x64"
Scores for cnt = 200 (writing/reading 5.07GB):
>>> main.benchmark(200)
Python - Write: 50.13 s
Python - Read: 20.21 s
Python - Total: 70.34 s

Dart (Synch) - Write: 28 s
Dart (Synch) - Read: 17 s
Dart (Synch) - Total: 45 s


To provide more granularity, I also tried to run the Dart benchmark scores using the function:
void benchmark({int cnt = 200}) {
  final blockSize = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' * (1024 * 1024);
  final filePath = 'large_benchmark_test.txt';
  final file = File(filePath);

  final clock = Stopwatch();
  clock.start();
  final sink = file.openSync(mode: FileMode.write);
  for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    sink.writeStringSync(blockSize);
  }
  sink.closeSync();
  clock.stop();
  final writeTime = clock.elapsedMicroseconds / 1e6;
  print("Dart (Synch) - Write: $writeTime s");

  clock.reset();
  clock.start();

  final reader = file.openSync(mode: FileMode.read);
  while (true) {
    final buffer = reader.readSync(1024);
    if (buffer.isEmpty) break;
  }
  reader.closeSync();
  clock.stop();

  final readTime = clock.elapsedMicroseconds / 1e6;
  final totalTime = writeTime + readTime;

  print("Dart (Synch) - Read: $readTime s");
  print("Dart (Synch) - Total: $totalTime s");
  file.deleteSync();
}

In the function above, a Stopwatch is used to calculate the scores. This makes it possible to write/read a smaller amount of data and still get a meaningful benchmark result.
Scores for cnt = 200 (writing/reading 5.07GB)
$ dart .\main.dart
Dart (Synch) - Write: 29.183918 s
Dart (Synch) - Read: 17.287486 s
Dart (Synch) - Total: 46.471404 s


Scores for cnt = 20 (writing/reading 520MB)
>>> main.benchmark(20)  
Python - Write: 5.86 s
Python - Read: 2.17 s
Python - Total: 8.02 s

$ dart .\main.dart
Dart (Synch) - Write: 3.447846 s
Dart (Synch) - Read: 2.434338 s
Dart (Synch) - Total: 5.8821840000000005 s

The benchmark scores above (generated on a Windows 11 system) do not reflect a huge difference in performance when writing/reading data using Python and Dart.
